# Method for calculating a value relative to min & max values

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to make a generic method i can use for calculating a value, in relation to max & min values i define.

I have this code

```
public static int CalculateRelation(int input, int inputMin, int inputMax, int outputMin, int outputMax)
{
    //Making sure bounderies arent broken...
    if (input > inputMax)
    {
        input = inputMax;
    }
    if (input < inputMin)
    {
        input = inputMin;
    }
    //Return value in relation to min og max
}
```

So fx if i do `CalculateRelation(0,0,180,150,500)` it would return `150`.. or if i did `CalculateRelation(180,0,180,150,500)` i would get `500`..

So the output is the number in relation to the bounderies set...

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes sense (proportional offset)

```
public static int CalculateRelation(int input, int inputMin, int inputMax, int outputMin, int outputMax)
{
    //Making sure bounderies arent broken...
    if (input > inputMax)
    {
        input = inputMax;
    }
    if (input < inputMin)
    {
        input = inputMin;
    }
    //Return value in relation to min og max

    double position = (double)(input - inputMin) / (inputMax - inputMin);

    int relativeValue = (int)(position * (outputMax - outputMin)) + outputMin);

    return relativeValue;
}
```

I believe this will do it, but don't have environment handy to verify.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, though there is a ) to much in the end of `relativeValue` calculation. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
var inputRange = (double)inputMax - inputMin;
var outputRange = (double)outputMax - outputMin;
var diff = (double)input - inputMin;
return (int)(diff / inputRangerange * outputRange + outputMin);
```

But I haven't actually tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
long result = input - inputMin;
result *= outputMax - outputMin;
result /= inputMax - inputMin;
result += outputMin;
```

Note, depending on the ranges here, you may overflow on the multiplication.  You could avoid that by pre-calculating the scaling factor as a double.

```
double scale = (double)(outputMax - outputMin)/(double)(inputMax - inputMin);
```

int result = outputMin + (int)((input - inputMin) * scale)